# Get a specific entry by group in SQL

Tags: php, sql, data-entry

I've a database who contain some datas in that form:

```
icon(name, size, tag)
(myicon.png, 16, 'twitter')
(myicon.png, 32, 'twitter')
(myicon.png, 128, 'twitter')
(myicon.png, 256, 'twitter')
(anothericon.png, 32, 'facebook')
(anothericon.png, 128, 'facebook')
(anothericon.png, 256, 'facebook')
```

So as you see it, the name field is not uniq I can have multiple icons with the same name and they are separated with the size field. Now in PHP I have a query that get ONE icon set, for example :

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM icon WHERE tag='".$tag."' ORDER BY size LIMIT 0, 10");
```

With this example if $tag contain 'twitter' it will show ONLY the first SQL data entry with the tag 'twitter', so it will be :

```
(myicon.png, 16, 'twitter')
```

This is what I want, but I would prefer the '128' size by default. Is this possible to tell SQL to send me only the 128 size when existing and if not another size ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You need an additional column to order by that puts the preferred value at the top.  For example, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM
  icon 
WHERE 
  tag='whatever' 
ORDER BY
  case size when 128 then 1 else 0 end desc,
  size desc
LIMIT 0, 10
```

The new `order by` clause puts your preferred size first (since it's the only one it assigns a 1 to), and then orders the rest of them by their actual size, biggest first.

Comment: Woow, I'm not sure to understand all your code. I will do some test.

Comment: Hmm that didn't run. Could you explain me more pls ?

Comment: In your example what's the additional column ? And what she contains ?

Comment: @Jensen : I edited in the full query.  Note that I didn't include any of the php code, so you'll have to wrap that in yourself.

Comment: When I test these lines I have an SQL error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case desc,
  size desc
LIMIT 0, 10' at line 8 

Do I need to add a column or another modification in my SQL database ?

Comment: Thanks, that's run ! Now I've a second query (the goal is the same) :

$dbQueryIcons = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pl_icon WHERE tag LIKE '%".$SEARCH_QUERY."%' ".$formSQLColor."&& size<='$formSizeMax' && size>='$formSizeMin' GROUP BY name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$firstEntry.", ".$CONFIG['icon_per_page']."") or die(mysql_error());

I want the same thing, only get the 128 (if existing) of each entry. The initial query is a little bit different than the other so how can I adapt your code with this query . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY size DESC`?

Comment: No because the 128 size is not necessarily the last data. I could have 16, 32, 128, 256 for example; so if I add DESC it would show me 256.